# Can I specify an integer constant by its bytes?

Tags: c++, c++11, elf

I'm using C++11 on a project of mine and was wondering how best to represent the ELF magic number. I'm not a fan of hex literals, so I was looking for something better than:

```
const uint32 ELF_MAGIC_NUMBER = 0x7F454c46; // 0x7F, E, L, F
```

So, I tried to write:

```
const uint32 ELF_MAGIC_NUMBER = { 0x7F, 'E', 'L', 'F' };
```

but the compiler complains that there are too many items in the initializer list, which is understandable, although annoying.

Is there any way to write an integer literal in terms of its bytes? I feel like the first option, while it works, is not as readable at the second.

Comment: The first doesn't have to be readable. That's what the comment and name for it are for. I'm probably only saying this because I don't think you're going to get better than a hex literal.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably going to take as much effort coding in a conversion as it is just to do the conversion yourself and include a comment.

Comment: `const union { uint8_t c[4]; uint32 u; } ELF_MAGIC_NUMBER = { 0x7F, 'E', 'L', 'F' };`, but that's just overly, superfluously complex.

Comment: Or maybe `const uint32 ELF_MAGIC_NUMBER = 0x7f << 24 | 'E' << 16 | 'L' << 8 | 'F';`, but again, is it worth the effort?

Comment: @chris Right, but I had to look up the mapping for 'E' => 45, 'L' => 4c, and 'F' => 46. It would be much nicer to not have to break my flow like that, and to not memorize the ASCII table.

Granted, I only had to do this once, but many magic numbers work this way.

Comment: @AlexReinking as I mention in my answer, whether you implement one of the solutions offered here or not, it is probably courteous to your readers to include the hex version of the number anyway.  So you will not escape from having to scan an ASCII table or something.

Comment: @chris but why should anyone care about the hex version when ELF defines the magic number to be 0x7F, 'E', 'L', 'F'? See page 11 of [this document](http://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs422/doc/ELF_Format.pdf) for example.

Comment: @AlexReinking for example, because it is easier to `grep` code for `0x...` than it is for `0x7f, 'E', ...`.

Comment: @Andrey Alright, fair enough. I was just trying to make my code more human-readable, rather than grep-readable.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since you can afford C++11, you could just define a little `constexpr` helper, which would enable compile-time evaluation:

```
#include <cstdint>

constexpr std::uint32_t from_bytes(char b1, char b2, char b3, char b4)
{
    return b4 + 
           (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(b3) << 8) + 
           (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(b2) << 16) + 
           (static_cast<std::uint32_t>(b1) << 24);
}
```

This way, your code won't look much different from the original version:

```
const std::uint32_t ELF_MAGIC_NUMBER = from_bytes(0x7F, 'E', 'L', 'F');

int main()
{
    static_assert(ELF_MAGIC_NUMBER == 0x7F454c46, "!");
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4bf1edb39f6955e).

Comment: Sorry I may be C-biased but I feel like there is legitimately no universe where this is simpler.  The C-style macro version of FROM_BYTES would be simpler imo.  Not that I advocate for that either.

Comment: @Andrey: I try to refrain from macros whenever I can, but well, I guess it's a matter of personal taste.

Comment: @Andrey: I'd just write `std::uint32_t(b3)`, ctor-style. I agree that the cast doesn't help readability. But I'd still use a function for typesafety.

Comment: I like it! Compile-time evaluation and I can write my code as I intend.

Comment: It's great. Will I have any problem to extend this function to using `...` and take an undefined number of arguments? I'm not on C++11 yet.

Comment: @TheMask: It shouldn't be too difficult. For instance a version based on variadic templates could look like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36805a93d650b085). Type-constraining through `std::enable_if` left as an exercise to the reader ;)

Answer (score 10):

Many compilers have this little known feature: multi-char character literals.

```
uint32 ELF_MAGIC_NUMBER = '\177ELF';
```

You'll have to use octal numbers for the non char, I'm afraid.

Ah, almost forgot! The meaning of that is compiler dependent, so I wouldn't do it.

But if you can use C++11 you can use `constexpr` and user-defined literals:

```
constexpr uint32_t operator "" _mc (const char *str, size_t len)
{
    return len==4? 
         (str[0] << 24) | (str[1] << 16) | (str[2] << 8) | str[3] : 
         throw "_mc literal must be of length 4";
}

constexpr uint32_t ELF_MAGIC_NUMBER = "\177ELF"_mc;
```

This has the nice feature that you can use string concatenation to use hexadecimal characters:

```
constexpr uint32_t ELF_MAGIC_NUMBER = "\x7F""ELF"_mc;
```

Comment: What if you skipped tue string concationation?

Comment: @Yakk: _octal-escape-sequence_ is defined as 1, 2 or 3 octal digits, but _hexadecimal-escape-sequence_ can have any number of hex digits, so "\x7FELF" will be parsed as three chars: `'\x7FE', 'L', 'F'`. Then, as the `operator""` is working on `char` and `CHAR_BITS` is most likely `8` the first char will be truncated to `0xFE`. Fortunately, my `len` check will catch it and give a compiler error.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
const uint32 i = 0x1000000 * 0x7F
               + 0x10000 * 'E'
               + 0x100 * 'L'
               + 0x1 * 'F';
```

Potentially more readable (a matter of opinion):

```
const uint32 i = 0x01000000 * 0x7F
               + 0x00010000 * 'E'
               + 0x00000100 * 'L'
               + 0x00000001 * 'F';
```

**Edit:** I'd amend my own answer by saying that even if you take an approach like this, you will probably want to include the hex version of the literal in your code as a comment, for the sake of people e.g. searching for the magic number in hex form, or seeing it elsewhere.  With this consideration in mind, since it is probably best to have the hex version in there anyway, it may be best as others have said to define the number in its hex form and add a comment as to what it represents, i.e. use your original version.

Comment: @nightcracker It might be worse than the original but it still constitutes an alternative to the original, which is what OP is asking for.

Comment: I figured which is why I removed my downvote immediately after.

Answer (score 4):

Doing the same task old way with using **template metaprogramming**

[metafunction idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Metafunction)

```
template <char a,char b,char c , char d>
struct  MAGIC_NUMBER {
    enum { value =d + 
           (static_cast<uint32_t>(c) << 8) + 
           (static_cast<uint32_t>(b) << 16) + 
           (static_cast<uint32_t>(a) << 24)  };
};




/*
 * usage
 */  
    const  uint32_t ELF_MAGIC_NUMBER = MAGIC_NUMBER<0x7F, 'E', 'L', 'F'>::value;
```

Answer (score 3):

Well this solution, using user-defined literals, is so ugly I might cry:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cassert>

uint32_t operator"" _u32s(const char* str, std::size_t size)
{
    std::istringstream ss(std::string(str, size));
    std::string token;
    int shift = 24;
    uint32_t result = 0;
    while (std::getline(ss, token, ',') && shift >= 0) {
        int value = 0;
        if (token.substr(0,2) == "0x") {
            std::stringstream hexss;
            hexss << std::hex << token;
            hexss >> value;
        } else if (token.length() == 1) {
            value = token[0];
        }
        result |= (value << shift);
        shift -= 8;
    }
    return result;
}

int main() {
    assert("0x7F,E,L,F"_u32s == 0x7F454c46);
}
```

Basically, you can now use the literal `"0x7F,E,L,F"_u32s`. Obviously it's nowhere near as nice as using a compile-time solution, but it's an interesting experiment.

Comment: I never thought to do this... this is actually really cool! +1 for ingenuity :)